# Need help when map table relationship in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot, persistence, hibernate-mapping

I'm working on `Spring Boot` + `Spring JPA` project. I'm using `Intellij persistence tool` to `generate` class from existing `oracle schema table`. 
I have 4 tables: Client, Users, Roles and Users_Roles. Below is sql for those table:

**Script for table Users**

```
CREATE TABLE "USERS" 
   (    "USER_ID" VARCHAR2(32 BYTE), 
    "USER_NAME" VARCHAR2(64 BYTE), 
    "PASSWORD" VARCHAR2(64 BYTE), 
    "BRANCH_ID" VARCHAR2(6 BYTE), 
    "GROUP_ID" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE), 
    "ENABLED" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE), 
    "CREATE_BY" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE), 
    "CREATED_ON" DATE, 
    "MODIFIED_BY" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE), 
    "MODIFIED_ON" DATE, 
    "VERSION_NUMBER" NUMBER(4,0), 
    "PREFERED_LOCALE" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) DEFAULT 'en', 
    "PREFERED_THEME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "FAILED_ATTEMPTS" NUMBER(3,0) DEFAULT 0, 
    "CLIENT_ID" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE), 
    "TEL" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "EMAIL" VARCHAR2(120 BYTE), 
    "C_SMS" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) DEFAULT 'false', 
    "C_IDEVICE" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) DEFAULT 'false', 
    "C_WEB" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) DEFAULT 'false', 
    "C_ANDROID" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) DEFAULT 'false', 
    "DEVICE_CODE" VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE) DEFAULT 'WEB', 
    "ISAUTHORIZE" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT "USERS_ENABLED_CHECK" CHECK ("ENABLED" IS NOT NULL) ENABLE NOVALIDATE, 
     CONSTRAINT "USERS_GROUP_ID_CHECK" CHECK ("GROUP_ID" IS NOT NULL) ENABLE NOVALIDATE, 
     CONSTRAINT "USERS_PASSWORD_CHECK" CHECK ("PASSWORD" IS NOT NULL) ENABLE NOVALIDATE, 
     CONSTRAINT "USERS_USER_NAME_CHECK" CHECK ("USER_NAME" IS NOT NULL) ENABLE NOVALIDATE, 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_USERS" PRIMARY KEY ("USER_ID", "CLIENT_ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "MPOS"  ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 3145728 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "MPOS" ;
```

**Script for table Roles**

```
CREATE TABLE "ROLES" 
   (    "ROLE_ID" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE), 
    "ROLE_NAME" VARCHAR2(64 BYTE), 
    "ENABLED" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE), 
    "CREATED_BY" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE), 
    "CREATED_ON" DATE, 
    "MODIFIED_BY" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE), 
    "MODIFIED_ON" DATE, 
    "VERSION_NUMBER" NUMBER(4,0), 
    "ROLE_GROUP" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT "ROLES_ENABLED_CHECK" CHECK ("ENABLED" IS NOT NULL) ENABLE NOVALIDATE, 
     CONSTRAINT "ROLES_ROLE_NAME_CHECK" CHECK ("ROLE_NAME" IS NOT NULL) ENABLE NOVALIDATE, 
     CONSTRAINT "ROLES_UNIQUE_KEY" UNIQUE ("ROLE_NAME")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 2097152 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "MPOS"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_ROLES" PRIMARY KEY ("ROLE_ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 2097152 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "MPOS"  ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 3145728 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "MPOS" ;
```

**Script for table Client**

```
CREATE TABLE "CLIENT" 
   (    "CLIENT_ID" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CLIENT_NAME" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "CLIENT_NAME_VI" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "CLIENT_SHORT_NAME" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "BIN" VARCHAR2(15 BYTE), 
    "URL" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "ENABLED" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE), 
    "CREATED_BY" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE), 
    "CREATED_ON" DATE, 
    "MODIFIED_BY" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE), 
    "MODIFIED_ON" DATE, 
    "VERSION_NUMBER" NUMBER, 
    "CHECK_METHOD" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
    "URL2" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "KEK" VARCHAR2(240 BYTE), 
    "KEKA" VARCHAR2(240 BYTE), 
    "KEKB" VARCHAR2(240 BYTE), 
    "DEK" VARCHAR2(240 BYTE), 
    "DEKA" VARCHAR2(240 BYTE), 
    "DEKB" VARCHAR2(240 BYTE), 
    "RMK" VARCHAR2(240 BYTE), 
    "RMKA" VARCHAR2(240 BYTE), 
    "RMKB" VARCHAR2(240 BYTE), 
    "STORE_IN" VARCHAR2(12 BYTE) DEFAULT 'HOST', 
    "KEK_A_KVC" VARCHAR2(8 BYTE), 
    "KEK_B_KVC" VARCHAR2(8 BYTE), 
    "DEK_A_KVC" VARCHAR2(8 BYTE), 
    "DEK_B_KVC" VARCHAR2(8 BYTE), 
    "RMK_A_KVC" VARCHAR2(8 BYTE), 
    "RMK_B_KVC" VARCHAR2(8 BYTE), 
    "KEK_KVC" VARCHAR2(8 BYTE), 
    "DEK_KVC" VARCHAR2(8 BYTE), 
    "RMK_KVC" VARCHAR2(8 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT "CLIENT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("CLIENT_ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "MPOS"  ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 131072 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "MPOS" ;
```

**Script for table Users_Roles**

```
CREATE TABLE "USERS_ROLES" 
   (    "USER_ID" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE), 
    "ROLE_ID" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE), 
    "SELECTED" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE), 
    "CREATED_BY" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE), 
    "CREATED_ON" DATE, 
    "MODIFIED_BY" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE), 
    "MODIFIED_ON" DATE, 
    "VERSION_NUMBER" NUMBER(4,0), 
    "CLIENT_ID" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT "USERSROLES_PRIMARY_KEY" PRIMARY KEY ("CLIENT_ID", "USER_ID", "ROLE_ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 131072 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "MPOS"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_USERSROLES_ROLE_ID" FOREIGN KEY ("ROLE_ID")
      REFERENCES "THUC"."ROLES" ("ROLE_ID") ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE NOVALIDATE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 3145728 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "MPOS" ;
```

According to the structure above, Users and Roles has many-to-many relationship. and Users has 2 primary keys: user_id and client_id. So, after generate class using persistence tool, in the `Users.java`, I define relationship:

```
@ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "USERS_ROLES",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
                    , @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
                    , @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    )
```

Then in `Roles.java`:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<Users> users;
```

However when I run project, errors apprear:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: roles, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(users)]
```

I need help to map relationship between them.

Any idea? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Regards & Thanks.

Comment: could do you add the Users class?

Comment: Yes, after add User class, I define @ManyToMany